# NodeJs server An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request

Tags: node.js, express

I created my first NodeJs app with express , and when i start the server and go to http://localhost:5000/ it gives this error.Any help would be appreciated

An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

[image: 1]

Comment: Hi Amine, this error is from an ASP.NET web application, not a NodeJS application. Is it at all possible that you've got a .NET web app process running in the background that you forgot to kill?

Comment: I don't have any apps running in the background , and the Port no 5000 is open.

Comment: changing the port to another free one seemed to work , thank you .

Answer (score 0):

You have a script running in the background or you haven't closed the database connection. Look in the process to see if the process is active

Show how you launch a project

Comment: I don't have a database on , the projet so far is a server.js file

const express = require("express");

var app = express();

app.listen(5000, function () {

console.log("Started application on port %d", 5000);

});

i run it using node server.js and it says Started application on port 5000

Comment: Might be port is occupied by another process try with different port number such as 3000

Comment: Welp changing the port worked , but for the life of me i can't understand why , I've checked port 5000 and its free , and when i tired using an occupied port on purpose the server won't start .
thank you